# Not able to catch request error using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I have the following code, which is supposed to catch errors and read status code from there

```
 useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await apiSettingsSite.fetchProductsCalc();
        console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response)
    }
},[])
```

but when 400 error happens i get null in the console from try block, code from catch is not even touched. Same with .then .catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you have a setting for axios i use like this:

```
const client = axios.create({ baseURL, json: true })

client.interceptors.response.use(undefined, async (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err)
})
```

Comment: I had something like this but fixing it did not help, in the console i am getting string representation of error from then(or try) block. Still can not access error message that is passes from backend

Comment: i have to see your code maybe you throw new Error. you have to reject the body

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what code inside the `fetchProductsCalc` function and what Axios config was used.

To test Axios request on own endpoint, you can use the following code:
[Live sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/use-async-effect-fetch-tiny-ui-states-g5qd7?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpAxios from "cp-axios";

function TestComponent(props) {
  const [cancel, done, result, err] = useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      return (yield cpAxios(props.url)).data;
    },
    { states: true, deps: [props.url] }
  );

  return (
    <div className="component">
      <div className="caption">useAsyncEffect demo:</div>
      <div>
        {done ? (err ? err.toString() : JSON.stringify(result)) : "loading..."}
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={cancel} disabled={done}>
        Cancel async effect
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the async function inside useEffect, rather then passing async function to useEffect.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function myFunc() {
    try {
      const response = await apiSettingsSite.fetchProductsCalc();
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  };

  myFunc();
}, []);
```

Comment: I did like you said but result is the same. Is there is possibility that this problem is caused by backed of my project ?

Comment: That could be the problem, you probably need to check the implementation of `apiSettingsSite.fetchProductsCalc()`